# KonvasJs drag limits

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I have a question about drag and drop on Konvasjs. If I do not set a dragBoundFunction, I can push my objects out of the stage/view. Is there no other function that prevents this?

Here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sV3n/pen/YMzRVx) with a dragBoundFunction, which prevents objects from beeing pushed out of the stage/context.

```
dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {

  return {      
      x: pos.x < 0 ? 0 : pos.x > (matrix.row - this.attrs.width / blockSize) * blockSize ? (matrix.row - this.attrs.width / blockSize) * blockSize : pos.x,
      y: pos.y < 0 ? 0 : pos.y > (matrix.col - this.attrs.height / blockSize) * blockSize ? (matrix.col - this.attrs.height / blockSize) * blockSize : pos.y,     
  }
}
```

Comment: As I can see your demo works well. What is your questing or issue? Or you don't want to use `dragBoundFunc`?

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering that I can drag my objects out of the view by default. Is there a reason why my canvas is actually bigger then my values I passed to my stage.